# Login por validación con intentos en Python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Estoy intentando crear un Login usando una base de datos en SQLite3, en el cual uso una tabla que se encuentra una columna llamada "intentos"", mi idea era por cada intento de introducir mal su usuario o clave el sistema lo bloquee. adjunto el codigo a ver si me pueden dar una mano.

```
 def login():
        # Conectando a DB
        db = sqlite3.connect('PDVdamoonplay.db')
        conexion = db.cursor()
        
        usuario = texto1.get()
        clave = texto2.get()
        intentos = conexion.execute('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE intentos')
        
        conexion.execute('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? AND clave = ?', (usuario, clave))
        
        if conexion.fetchall():
            acceso_Ventana_Main()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(title = "ERROR", message = "Usuario o clave es incorrecta, por favor intente de nuevo")
            dec_intentos = intentos -1
            if dec_intentos == 0:
                messagebox.showerror(title = "ERROR", message = "Usuario bloqueado")
```

Comment: nomás digo que a esa variable `intentos` le falta un igual

Comment: Gracias! no me habia dado cuenta